# nullable generic interface type for self referenceable entities

Tags: c#

```
public class MyClass : ISelfReferenceable<Guid>
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public Guid? ParentId {get;set;}
}
public interface ISelfReferenceable<TId>
{
     TId Id {get;set;}
     TId? ParentId {get;set;}
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why the above does not work?

It shouts [Compiler Error CS0738](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0738?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0738))

> 'type name' does not implement interface member 'member name'. 'method name' cannot implement 'interface member' because it does not have the matching return type of ' type name'.

on `MyClass.ParentId`, saying that it doesn't implement `ISelfReferenceable.ParentId`, unless I change `MyClass.ParentId` from `Guid?` to `Guid`.

Currently, I get around this by using two generic types, one for `Id` and another for `ParentId`, or simply make `ParentId` `Guid` instead of `Guid?`.

Is this the right approach and is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `TId?` is interpreted as a nullable reference type *(in fact this is more complicated and depends on the language version and whether you are in a nullable context. See also the explanation under [default constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#default-constraint))*. You can fix it by adding a `where TId : struct` generic type constraint to the interface. But of course this limits the applicable types to value types. A `string` Id would not be possible.

The error also goes away if you declare

```cs
public class MyClass : ISelfReferenceable<string>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it suits your purpose, but it compiles with this:

```cs
public interface ISelfReferenceable<TId> where TId : struct
{
     TId Id {get;set;}
     TId? ParentId {get;set;}
}
```

Remember that `Guid` is a value type.